# UNION function mysql not accepting ORDER BY date

Tags: mysql, sql

Im trying to extract data using this query:

```
select fnl_res.id, fnl_res.business_name, fnl_res.owner_name from (
(select b_infos.id, b_infos.business_name, b_infos.owner_name, orders.date from b_infos 
    inner join orders on b_infos.id = orders.businessId) 
UNION
( select b_infos.id, b_infos.business_name, b_infos.owner_name from b_infos 
    inner join expenses_logs on b_infos.id = expenses_logs.businessId ) ) as fnl_res
```

It works fine but when i add a column date and order by date on each union:

```
select fnl_res.id, fnl_res.business_name, fnl_res.owner_name, orders.date from (
(select b_infos.id, b_infos.business_name, b_infos.owner_name, orders.date from b_infos 
    inner join orders on b_infos.id = orders.businessId ORDER BY orders.date) 
UNION
( select b_infos.id, b_infos.business_name, b_infos.owner_name, expenses_logs.date from b_infos 
    inner join expenses_logs on b_infos.id = expenses_logs.businessId  ORDER BY expenses_logs.date ) ) as fnl_res
```

I got this error:
Error code 1114: The table is full!

Already research this error says im trying to insert but im just selecting on the table

Is there something i need to consider?

Comment: The title of your question mentions "order by date", but this does not appear in your query. Please correct either the title or query so they are aligned. Also, please include a [mcve], ideally as a link to an online query playground such as http://sqlfiddle.com et al.

Comment: sorry forgot to include its already updated thanks

Comment: ORDER BY without a limit inside the subquery is useless. Check check if the disk on the server is full `df -h` , check `tmp_table_size` and `max_heap_table_size` as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MySQL, `order by` may not appear within a subquery. Wrap the whole query up as a subquery and apply `order by` to that:

```sql
select *
from (
  select
    b_infos.id, b_infos.business_name, b_infos.owner_name, orders.date
    from b_infos 
    join orders on b_infos.id = orders.businessId 
  union
  select
    b_infos.id, b_infos.business_name, b_infos.owner_name, expenses_logs.date
    from b_infos 
    join expenses_logs on b_infos.id = expenses_logs.businessId
) x
order by 4 -- order by the 4th column
```

Note that without `where` clauses, you're going to return every row, possibly blowing memory and causing your error. Consider some filtering, perhaps `where orders.date > '2022-10-13'`